# Adding nodes to a linked list in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

The addToList() function takes a value as an argument. Values are passed to the addToList() function many times consecutively.

```
def addToList(value):
    node = {}
    node["data"] = value
    node["next"] = None
    head = node
```

The question is: how do I create many different nodes? Each value that comes in should be assigned to a node. Only the first node should be equal to head. As of now, I'm creating one node, giving it a value, and then when the next value comes in I overwrite the node I had made instead of creating a new one. How would each new node point to a different ["next"]? If I know my values ahead of time, I can program each node manually. I don't understand how to generate new and unique nodes when I don't know how many values I will have, and they are being fed to a function.

Comment: addToList should accept **two** arguments. Value and current head (list), otherwise you might have a single list in the global scope which you are extending.

Comment: The list itself represents the head?

Comment: the other way around, head represents the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pretty much two possibilities (unless you want to go to object oriented code, then there is a third option). For simplicity I assume that we add element in front (and not at the end) of the list.

#### global scope

Meaning that you have just one list at the time

```
head = None
def addToList(value):
    global head
    head = {'value': value, 'next': head}

addToList(3)
addToList(5)
addToList(11)
print head
```

or using actual lists:

```
actual_list = []
def addToList(value):
    global actual_list
    actual_list.append(value)

addToList(3)
addToList(5)
addToList(11)
print actual_list
```

#### two arguments

```
def addToList(value, head):
    return {'value': value, 'next': head}

head = None
head = addToList(3, head)
head = addToList(5, head)
head = addToList(11, head)
print head
```

and again using actual lists

```
def addToList(value, actual_list):
    actual_list.append(value)

actual_list = []
addToList(3, actual_list)
addToList(5, actual_list)
addToList(11, actual_list)
print actual_list
```

Comment: Following the two arguments route, how would you traverse the linked list?

Comment: you take a head as an argument and loop over. There is no difference. In particular printing is already "traversing" it, as you can see by running the snippet.

Answer (score -1):

the easy answer to your question to make each node point to correct next is to make your function as

```
def addToList(value):
    node = {}
    node["data"] = value
    node["next"] = None
    head[next] = node
    head = node
```

but you need to keep track of the real head of your list somewhere else so you can travese your list later from head to tail

here is complete example

```
head={}
head["data"] = "start"
head["next"] = None
start = head
def addToList(value):
    global head
    node = {}
    node["data"] = value
    node["next"] = None
    head["next"] = node
    head = node

addToList("second")
addToList("third")

print start
```

it will print this

```
{'data': 'start', 'next': {'data': 'second', 'next': {'data': 'third', 'next': None}}}
```

Comment: this will not work. `head` is a local variable in such scope in python, it will raise an error. Plus assignment of both head[next] and head itself to the same values makes no sense

Comment: when doing head[next] = node head was pointing to last head which is the last object , so we make the last head object point to this new node. then we make the last node is the new node so on next insertion we will get correct head . rethink it

Comment: Example uses "global", which answer does not :-) plus variable "head" does not store "head" of the list, it stores a "tail" (reference to the last element).